# Why do brackets in SQL around field name not work in Access VBA ADO?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In MS Access QBE if I paste the following SQL, it works correctly and I get 2 records back-

```
SELECT [tmp_binning].[bn_faibash] FROM [tmp_binning] WHERE key2='0210043-HOU-STOR' ORDER BY [tmp_binning].[bn_faibash];
```

But if I programmatically run the same query in VBA from an ADO object I get (incorrectly) no records. If I change the SQL to remove brackets around the field name, it does correctly return the 2 records in VBA ADO.

```
SELECT [tmp_binning].bn_faibash FROM [tmp_binning] WHERE key2='0210043-HOU-STOR' ORDER BY [tmp_binning].bn_faibash;
```

I've been unsuccessful googling to figure why this happens on my own, can anyone tell me why?

Thanks.

Comment: Who cares why the syntax is different? Every flavor of SQL is a little different. SQL Server T-SQL is different from Oracle is different from DB2 is different from Teradata is different from My SQL.

Comment: Uh, it's not using a different SQL dialect, just a different interface. It shouldn't be different. But, again, this is yet another argument for using naming conventions that never require brackets. It's also, in my opinion, an argument for never using ADO.

Comment: @DOK, I care that I understand why strange discrepancies happen in a tool that I am using, and whether it is my error or a strange glitch. Also it isn't a different dialect as David pointed out. @David, I also don't like naming conventions that require spaces, but I am supporting a previously written tool that would take a lot of work to remove all the bad prior practices like this. Do you feel like DAO is more reliable than ADO? Thanks.

Comment: For working with Jet/ACE data from Access, hands down DAO is the proper interface (and always has been). From outside Access, it depends on the tools you're using whether ADO or DAO is the best choice. Classic ADO is dead on all platforms, so I would be wary of using it in any environment.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I do not think that is quite true: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/458870-ado-dead-2-a

Comment: @Remou: Have you ever actually compared ADO.NET to Classic ADO? The differences are significant, once you get past the superficial similarities that every database abstraction interface is going to have. Classic ADO is dead, and the article you cite doesn't address that -- it only tries to argue that ADO.NET is a successor to Classic ADO. While this is true when you're working in an environment like ASP vs. ASP.NET, it's completely inapplicable to COM environments.

Comment: ADO is still extremely useful with VBA and VBScript, ADO.Net is a different thing altogether.

Comment: Seems to me, ADO is useful only where DAO doesn't provide the features that ADO does. I've never used it in VBScript, for example, always using DAO instead (for working with Jet/ACE data, of course). But your assertion doesn't really refult my original assertion, that outside Access something other than DAO may be a better choice.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I can go one better: OLE DB (not limited to ADO) is essential where no other interface (including DAO and the Access UI) provides the features that OLE DB does. If you are tied in to VBA6 and OLE DB is essential ergo ADO is needed. MDAC continues to be updated for Windows releases, long after Jet was removed. Rumours of ADO's death have been greatly exaggerated ;)

Comment: Uh, DAO and MDAC are not related. Jet and DAO are included as part of Windows, which was why they were removed from the MDAC, so you don't really give a rat's ass about MDAC versions if you're using Jet 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

First, the brackets aren't required, either in the in Access UI or via ADO. Simply omit them in all environments and the problem should go away. (If it is the Access QBE thing that is adding the brackets then consider another tool or hand crafting your SQL code!)

Second, even with the brackets I can't reproduce the error using your SQL code e.g.

```
Sub gjskdjs()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String


      Sql = _
          "CREATE TABLE tmp_binning" & vbCr & "(" & vbCr & " bn_faibash VARCHAR(255)," & _
          " " & vbCr & " key2 VARCHAR(255)" & vbCr & ");"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
          "INSERT INTO tmp_binning (bn_faibash, key2)" & _
          " VALUES ('002', '0210043-HOU-STOR');"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
          "INSERT INTO tmp_binning (bn_faibash, key2)" & _
          " VALUES ('001', '0210043-HOU-STOR');"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
          "SELECT [tmp_binning].bn_faibash " & vbCr & "  FROM" & _
          " [tmp_binning] " & vbCr & " WHERE key2 = '0210043-HOU-STOR'" & _
          " " & vbCr & " ORDER " & vbCr & "    BY [tmp_binning].bn_faibash;"
      Dim rs
      Set rs = .Execute(Sql)
      MsgBox rs.GetString
    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

Consider posting your schema as SQL DDL with sample data.

Comment: This was initially part of a VBA function I was trying to abstract out to use with multiple tables, some unfortunately have spaces in the table or field name. So the brackets are required unless I spend a lot of time revising out all the spaces in the many tables, fields, and VBA functions. When I got erroneous results from the VBA function, I took one example of the SQL it would run, and found it worked fine in QBE. I discovered if the brackets around the field names were removed in VBA, it worked fine. I will try to write up code to recreate the DB but it may take a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered creating a saved QueryDef that aliases the problematic table/field names to ones that don't require brackets, and then using that? I'm not sure if it would bypass the error you're encountering, but if I had to do what you're describing, I'd consider it.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: if you are suggesting creating a `VIEW` to rename the columns that have spaces then it sounds good to me. But `QueryDef` is a DAO object and proposing a conversion from ADO to DAO is not appropriate.

Comment: In Access/Jet/ACE, "saved QueryDef" is the right terminology, and that's why it's used in DAO. In other words, you have it backwards -- DAO uses the term because DAO is a wrapper around Jet/ACE, not the other way around. Access/Jet/ACE documentation never uses the term "view" even though it's technically correct to apply it to a saved QueryDef.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton -- The Access help uses the term "query" e.g. here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/about-sql-queries-mdb-HP005188412.aspx makes clear that a "QueryDef" is distinct from a query: "You can also use SQL statements programmatically in: ...The SQL property of a QueryDef object to change the underlying SQL statement of a query." i.e. the underlying object is called a "query" and use can use something else called a "QueryDef" to change its SQL statement.

Comment: ...You'd probably agree with me that the decision to call a persisted object that contains a SQL statement a "query" was a poor one. In the general SQL language terms, a query is a SELECT statement that returns a resultset (and would exclude a `SELECT..INTO` statement). The SQL statement an Access "query" can contain may not be a query at all e.g. could be a DML (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`), DDL ('CREATE TABLE`, `DROP PROCEDURE`, etc) or DCL (`BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES`). For the same reasons,  I don't think QueryDef is a good candidate either.

Comment: You seem to have confused Access terminology with Jet/ACE/DAO terminology. Whatever you may believe is good terminology, certainly grabbing terms that are not used in any of the Access/Jet/ACE documentation (except in the obscure corners documenting features that are not widely used by most users of Jet/ACE, e.g., DDL) seems misguided to me. I just can't vote for using foreign terminology for something that's already clear and established in all the documentation.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I don't think I am confused. Rather, I should say, as far as I am aware `QueryDef` only applies in DAO and not in Jet, ACE, Access Database Engine, etc, generally. Can you post some links to the documentation that shows otherwise...?

Comment: DAO is all over the Access documentation, thus QueryDef is everywhere in Access documentation. I don't think I need to reply any links to demonstrate that fact. It's used all over the Jet Database Engine Programmer's Guide (which was never published online). It's simply standard terminology when working with Jet/ACE because DAO is the standard interface for doing so.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: all the usual disinformation and no evidence in support. Why am I not surprised?

Comment: @onedaywhen: I have to support David Fenton here.  He is simply arguing that one should use the terminology conventions of the Access environment when discussing the Access environment.  To use the term View in that environment is to introduce a foreign term.  Also, a cursory Google search for `jet querydef` yielded this as the first result (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966376.aspx) which includes the text "For information about creating QueryDef objects, see the "Microsoft Jet QueryDef Objects" section later in this chapter."

Comment: Further: "MS Jet QueryDef Objects

As its name implies, a QueryDef object is the definition of a query, either saved permanently in a Microsoft Jet database, or created as a temporary object. A QueryDef object doesn't contain any data or perform an action; it's merely the set of instructions Microsoft Jet uses to select information or perform an action, such as the deletion or insertion of records in a database table."

Comment: But wait, there's more: "Not everything that can be stored in a QueryDef object is what is usually thought of as a "query." In addition to SQL SELECT statements, which select, join, and order information from one or more tables, a QueryDef object can contain an SQL DELETE, INSERT, or CREATE TABLE statement. "

Comment: Finally, even though a QueryDef is a DAO object, you can still use QueryDefs in SQL statements that you pass via ADO.

Comment: @phoog: you have to bear in mind that the source you are quoting is quite old (even by Access standard :): it pre-dates both ADO and the ANSI-92 Query Mode that supports `CREATE VIEW`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, etc. So the fact it doesn't mention `VIEW` should not be surprising. Also, it was written in the stage of the product's development when it was merely a file sharing application (some would say it still is...) and bore MSFT and the SQL Server team tried to turn it into a SQL product, for which Entry Level SQL-92 compliance is a prerequisite (same they didn't quite get there).

Comment: @phoog: the first time the article mentions QueryDef it qualifies it as a DAO object i.e. "Another way to execute an SQL statement is to create a permanent DAO QueryDef object". Subsequently, the 'DAO' qualifier is later dropped and just 'QueryDef' is used. This is a very common writing style, similar to when a person's full name is first used ("Bill Gates") and subsequently just their surname is used ("Gates") because using their full name each time can become wearying to read.

Comment: @phoog: "one should use the terminology conventions of the Access environment when discussing the Access environment" -- "Access" is a many faceted thing. One of those faces is its ANSI-92 Query Mode, entirely relevant for the subject in hand ("Access VBA ADO") and for which QueryDef has no meaning. Saying QueryDef is "correct" and saying/implying `VIEW` isn't... well, that's simply misguided.

Comment: The date of the article cited does not change the fact that IT IS STILL ACCURATE about the way the Access documentation refers to its own objects. For instance, Access terminology still uses QUERY for all types of saved SQL statements, while FOREIGN terminology would use VIEW and SPROC for those same saved SQL statements. QueryDef maps directly onto the terminologly used in all the Access help (including the current Access help), as well as in all the documentation (spotty and incomplete as it is) for Jet/ACE. You are simply WRONG here.

Comment: "it was written in the stage of the product's development when it was merely a file sharing application (some would say it still is...)" Anybody who DOES NOT stay it sill is a "file-sharing application" does not have even the most basic understanding of the Jet/ACE database engine. So your point is simply WRONG.

Comment: SQL 92 mode DOES NOT WORK with basic Access objects, like multi-column combo boxes with AutoExpand turned on. Turning it on switches you to a completely different set of RESERVED WORDS than the standard Access defaults. IT DOESN'T WORK. It's another of those things that MS introduced into Access for external purposes and does not serve the needs of Access developers or users at any level.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: when you think ANSI-92 Query Mode (to use its *correct* name ;) think `CHECK` constraints e.g. Does every table require a key in the database? Yes. Can every table's key be enforced using `PRIMARY KEY`? No (example: a valid-state 'history' temporal table requires a sequenced key). Can every table's key be enforced using `CHECK` constraints (bugs in the DBMS aside)? Yes. Can I create a `CHECK` in Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) without using ANSI-92 Query Mode? No. Does ANSI-92 Query Mode serve the needs of Access developers? Yes. Q.E.D.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: We can agree that SQL statements are oft referred to as a "queries" by Access users and Microsoft, ditto the objects cretaed when storing a SQL statement in a mdb etc. I hope my point about "query" being inaccurate and vague is not completely lost on you.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: My personal preference is to use the Access SQL (not foreign) keywords "VIEW" and "PROCEDURE" because it provides further layer of granularity. There are important differences between the two e.g. a `VIEW` can be queried as a table (for that is what it is) and a `PROCEDURE` can be executed to update data (or metadata). My personal preference may not be to your taste but it isn't 'wrong'. Not wrong because it is based on Access keywords and reproducible behaviour (e.g. a `VIEW` cannot be executed). Unless you have a proof for my "wrongness"...?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: meanwhile, back on my original point... I see no evidence that "saved QueryDef" is the "right" terminology. Sure, its one terminology but it is specific to DAO. No doubt if you use DAO a lot you may begin to mistake the trees for the wood ;) And for this reason it may turn up in articles, even those penned by Microsoft. But the term "QueryDef" isn't used in the Access UI, isn't used in OLE DB, isn't used in SQL, isn't used in the Access object model, etc. So I'm still not convinced by your "QueryDef is correct" assertion but please keep the *evidence* coming.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand the obvious, because it seems you don't actually use Access. When you suggst using SQL 92 mode, most users of Access will interpret that as meaning you turn on SQL 92 mode in the Access UI. Since you don't actually use Access and are thus insensitive the context in which you are using the terminology, I think I would have to interpret what you are referring to is using ADO to execute the SQL (which uses SQL 92 mode no matter what setting you've got for your database). But you didn't say that, so your comments are REALLY CONFUSING. And thus not particuarly helpful.

Comment: The point here is that you are talking about something COMPLETELY DIFFERENT than is implied within the context. You make the same mistake in regard to SQL 92 mode that you make with querydef vs. view -- you're applying outside terminology that people who use Access and the Access documentation are going to find foreign. This is not helpful.

Comment: You are wrong in asserting that your use of terminology is helpful to Access users. Perhaps some (or even many) will be familiar with non-Access terminology and will be able to figure out what you mean. But if you're answering an Access question, I think it would make sense to adopt the Access context and use Access terminology first (even if you also provide the foreign terms as clarification; or vice versa, for that matter). You're wrong that it's helpful to insist on foreign terminology -- it simply makes things less clear.

Comment: The term "QueryDef" is used by Access developers talking about Access and helping others. Perhaps it came into general usage from the DAO documentation, and perhaps it's not used in the Access help files (I'm not convinced of this, though won't ask you to prove a negative; I don't care enough about the issue to attempt to disprove you), unless you define the Access help files as not including the VBA help that links to DAO help. I don't know what forums you've been reading over the years, but "QueryDef" is ubiquitous throughout. It is clear and concise and nobody is confused by it.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I accept what you say about QueryDef being used by Access developers talking about Access and it coming into usage from the DAO documentation. Now, note *this* question is about ADO and it is tagged 'sql' (if it wasn't tagged 'sql' I wouldn't have read it). How does one create a "saved QueryDef" using ADO or SQL?

Comment: The same way you'd do it with pure SQL within Access. But nobody would be likely to do that, of course, as it makes no sense to use Jet/ACE's spotty DDL implementation when you've got a full object model at your fingertips to manipulate everything fully (i.e., DAO).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "The same way you'd do it with pure SQL within Access" -- I assume you imply using `CREATE VIEW` but don't dare say it. You could also use ADOX and call `Add` on its `Views` collection.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: as you know, DAO is not 'full': it has omissions from the Jet 4.0 era. First, there are those that can only be created using SQL DDL: `CHECK` constraints, 'fast' foreign keys, fixed width data types, compressible data types, step and seed for `IDENTITY`, etc. Second, there are further features omitted from DAO: default values for parameters when creating a "query", precision and scale for `DECIMAL`, RefreshCache and transaction commit mode e.g. for custom counters, etc.

Comment: There are just as many things missing from the DDL implementation as there are missing from DAO. And, of course, there's no reason that both omissions could not be rectified if MS chose to do so.